# PHP if function unable to become true with dates involved

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make an if function for a Wordpress theme that says, if todays date is earlier than the provided date in the backend, display the word upcoming, else, say previous.

Here is the code, bare in mind that I have never tried to compare dates in PHP.

```
<?php if (the_field( 'closing_night' ) > date( 'M' . 'D' . 'Y' )) {
    echo 'Upcoming';
} 
      else{echo 'Previous'; }
?>
```

It is always displaying the date provided in the_field( 'closing_night' ) and then the word previous, no matter what.

What happened?

Comment: You're comparing date *strings*. Don't do that. Either compare timestamps, or create DateTime objects using `DateTime` class and compare them.

Comment: Sorry, like I said I am new to using dates, how do I go about that?

Comment: http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: Note that using `the_field` will print the value of the field. You probably meant to use `get_field` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<?php

if (strtotime(get_field('closing_night')) > strtotime('today')) {
    echo 'Upcoming';
} else {
    echo 'Previous';
}
```

Comment: No, it is not. `strtotime('now') == time()`;